# Line integral of tangential component

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, line-integrals

I am given $f(x,y,z) = 7y^2+5e^{xz}+\ln(6(x^2+y^2+z^2))$
where the vectorfield is defined through $F(x,y,z) = \nabla f(x,y,z)$. 
Now I am asked to calculate the integral of the tangential component of $F$ along the curve$$x = 8\sin(3\theta)\cos(\theta)$$
$$y = 8\sin(3\theta)\sin(\theta)$$
$$z = 8\cos(3\theta)$$.

I'm confused about how to set this integral up, the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{dx}$, $\frac{\partial f}{dy}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{dz}$ yield some nasty expressions, I don't believe I'm supposed to use these in my integral. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hint: That is a closed curve, and $f$ has no line of singularities inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the curve does not pass through $(0,0,0)$ and the vector field is the gradient of some function $f(x,y,z)$ which does not have any line of singularities inside the curve.  (In fact, it only has a point singularity at the origin.)

Therefore, the gradient theorem applies, and the integral along the curve from point $p$ to point $q$ is $f(p)-=f(q)$

Thus the integral of $F \cdot ds$  along the whole curve (where starting and ending points $p$ and $q$ are identical) will be $f(p)-f(p) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance! I see now that I forgot to add from the parametervalue $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$. Does this mean I just substitute x,y,z from the parametric equation into f and then take $f(\pi/2)-f(0)$?

Comment: Nvm, you just plug the values into x,y,z and then into $f$ ofcourse.. Getting late again...